# Mage_Catalog - missing <helpers> config node

Tags: helper

In the Mage_Catalog module etc/config.xml there is no  config node.

However, catalog helpers can obviously still be loaded via Mage::helper.

How is this possible?

Comment: Great question btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has a fallback on `Mage_<your package>_Helper_<your_class>`, this means:

`Mage::helper('catalog/image')` will be resolved to `Mage_CATALOG_Helper_IMAGE`.

If you don't define your helper in your module, like `MyCompany_MyModule`, you might have already seen the error:

```
Class not found: Mage_MyCompany_MyModule_Helper_Data
```

All this happens here:

```
\Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1254 (EE 1.13.1 (?))
if (empty($className)) {
    $className = 'mage_'.$group.'_'.$groupType;
}
```